# How long does it take for an application to get cancelled (UK VISA)

Tags: visas, uk

I applied for a UK visa online with all my details and submitted
the application. Also paid the application fee online.

The next day I realized that I made a few errors in my application. I
did not want to get a rejection because of those small
mistakes (basically didn't want to take chances). So I cancelled my
application online.

I received an email from UK visa stating that "you will receive an
email when a decision will be made".

Now I need to reapply again as soon as possible.

So how long do they take to cancel an application so that I can reapply or can I reapply now while they are making the decision on my previous application?

Comment: I have the same situation. I cancelled my application before bio metric. How long did you wait for your application to be cancelled?

Comment: seems you haven't checked my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to answer my own question

You can reapply immediately after cancelling your online application (considering you havent appeared yet for your bio metric or you still have days left for your bio metric)

Answer (score 6):

The timing sequence is difficult to tell from what you have written but, if you received an email that your application had been received at the Home Office, you would be unable to cancel at that point.

Your online account should tell you the status (where it is in the process). If you are able to withdraw the application, it could be 2-4 business days, depending on when you submitted your request.

You should not reapply until you know the status of the current application; if you try to, the online system sees that you already have an account and an active application.

> **[Cancel your visa, immigration or citizenship application](https://www.gov.uk/cancel-visa)**
>
> You can ask to cancel (withdraw) an application for a visa, visa extension or citizenship.
>
> How you cancel an application depends on where you applied.
>
> **You applied outside the UK**
>
> [Contact UKVI](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk) to find out how to cancel your application.
>
> You can only get your fee refunded if your application hasn’t been processed yet.
>
> **You applied in the UK**
>
> You need to [cancel your application using the online form](http://%20cancel%20your%20application%20using%20the%20online%20form.).
>
> > You won’t get your fee refunded if you cancel an application that you made in the UK.
>
> It’s sometimes possible to get your passport or other documents returned without withdrawing your application - you’ll be told whether you can do this when you fill in the form.
>
> You may lose your permission to stay in the UK if you cancel your application.
>
> You can’t stop the cancellation once it’s been received by the Home Office.